# float32 and precision points in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand presision points in python between `np.float32` and `np.float64`. For lower memory footprint I am leaning towards using float32 but I dont quite understand why sometimes a float turns into an iterger-like. For example:

```
x = np.array(12345678.1234) # this is an float64 by default
z = 5 * x
```

then z is another np.float64 with value 6172835.617

However if I cast this as a np.float32, then `np.float32(z) = 61728390.0`. It cant be some kind of buffer overflow, the range of float32 is -/+ 3.4e+38

Comment: There a lot of posts over the net If you want to dive into details on how floats work internally and why. Or you might want to watch this https://youtu.be/Oo89kOv9pVk

Comment: The problem is one of precision.  A float32 doesn't have enough precision to keep decimal places past about 7 digits.

Comment: @Mark Yeah. To demonstrate: `np.float32(z) + np.float32(1) == np.float32(z)` → `True`

Comment: Thanx everyone! yes i can see now what I am missing! thnx again for helping out

Comment: @wjandrea the one thing that still bugs me is why numpy keeps choosing `61728390.0` in its rounding.  Python chooses `61728392.0` for the same bit pattern.